# Print Bits In C

Tags: c, unix

My C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  unsigned int x = 0x70;
  printf("%02X", x);
  return 0;
}
```

I then redirect this code, (which is called myp to a file)

```
./myp > quickfile
```

I then xxd the new quickfile and it returns:

```
 0000000: 3730          70
```

And, if I go xxd -b quickfile:

```
 0000000: 00110111 0011000
```

I need it to say the first byte is 70 when I xxd quickfile. and I need the -b option to show 01110000 as the first byte. How do I do this????

Comment: If you mean the first byte of the output file must have the value 0x70, change printf to `printf("%c", x);`

Comment: Thanks, ash. That seemed to work.

Comment: Glad to help.  I recommend reading a little more about printf() and write().  In the case of writing small, specific, byte-accurate data, write() can be simpler.